# Send an extra model to JsonResource in order to add a column to the first model

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model with 5 instances called level and another one called member. For given member I need to call a JsonResource for each level and add a column on toArray method called available. In order to do that I need to pass somehow the member id along with the level instance to JsonResource, something like this:

```
$levels = Level::with('reward')->get();
$result = collect();
foreach ($levels as $level) {
$result->push(new RoadmapResource($level,$member_id);
}
```

Of course this won't work because toArray accepts only 1 parameter so I need a way to pass both so I can do the needed calculations before adding the new column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass the second param in the `__contstruct` like this here:

```
public function __construct($resource, $param) {  parent::__construct($resource);}
```

Comment: That actually worked Thanks! I tried something like that at some point but something wasn't working so I gave up. Seeing your answer made me try again.